# Como crear dos spinner enlazados en SWIFT

Tags: swift

Tengo dos spinner enlazados en Android y funcionan sin problemas, pero no sé como replicarlos en SWIFT... Alguien sabe cómo se hace o cómo se llama la herramienta?

He visto algunos videos de pickerview y de dropdownmenu pero no he visto ninguno que enlace a dos de ellos. Es decir, si escojo un País X quiero que me aparezcan las ciudades de ese País X en el otro spinner...

Espero puedan ayudarme,
desde ya,
muchas gracias.

Comment: tienes fotos de lo que quieres hacer? o algo que se le parezca?

Answer (score 0):

Usa Interface Builder para añadir las ruedas (UIPicker) y luego crea un @IBOutlet al controlador de la vista para controlarlo con código. En la página de Apple se especifican los métodos que puedes utilizar para ver qué fila está seleccionada, selectedRow por un lado; y por otro cambiar los elementos de la rueda, con la propiedad dataSource y el método reloadComponent.

Ahora bien, puedes usar un mismo UIPicker con los dos campos que necesitas, lo más recomendable, o poner dos distintos de un solo campo.

A partir de aquí el código es prácticamente hacer un switch para cada país.
Si tienes alguna duda, no dudes en consultarla.

Un saludo.

Comment: las respuestas mas que comentarios, deben ser una muestra de código y la explicación del mismo; por otro lado trata de mejora tu redacción, se hace difícil seguir la guía de alguien que escribe todo continuo

Comment: @shadow trata de mejorar tu comprensión lectora. No proveo código porque entiendo que es sencillo de hacer. Si alguien tiene problemas al respecto lo introduciré en mi solución. Además su problema no es de código, sino de falta de conocimiento de los elementos propios de UIKit. Es por esto que le indico qué herramientas puede usar para resolver su problema, que una vez conocidas deberían ser fáciles de utilizar.

Comment: Las respuestas deben ser código y explicación, es decir no dejarlo para después por otro lado pedirte que mejores la estructura de tu respuesta es necesario para todos los que la revisen a futuro

Comment: @shadow, ¿dónde está especificado en la guía del sitio que las repuestas deban tener código? Yo no lo he encontrado. Por otro lado puedes mejorar tu puntuación y no criticar que “escribo todo continuo” cuando en tus comentarios no hay un solo punto.